# flag provided but not defined: -oppose-dao-fork

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, ethereum-classic, hardforks

I just tried synching to the Ethereum Classic blockchain with `geth --oppose-dao-fork`. I was using Ubutntu PPAs but I hit an error at a certain (can't find which one now) which was a known issue with that version of geth.

I compiled geth from source and am now using version `1.6.7-unstable-dfd07624`.

Now when I try to continue synching the chain, I get

```
flag provided but not defined: -oppose-dao-fork
```

How do use Ethereum Classic with the latest geth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this flag has now been removed. (I can't find it in the source code, but neither can I find the commit that removed it... It's definitely not there though.)

I imagine the two forks - ETH and ETC - have now diverged to the point that supporting both versions in one codebase would be a burden to the ETH developers.

Ethereum Classic has had its own [homepage](https://ethereumclassic.github.io/), [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum), and official [releases](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/releases) for a while now. You should be able to find what you need there.